# ASMX web services and MVC in single assembly with 2 separate subdomains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis, iis-7.5

I have 2 assemblies in my solution:

```
MySite <- MVC site
MySiteServices <- ASMX services
```

Which maps to this setup in IIS:

```
http/https://example.com -> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite
http/https://services.example.com -> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysiteservices
```

This causes my deployments to be more complicated than I would like, so I want to merge the web services into the MVC project.  In other words, like this:

```
http/https://example.com -> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite
http/https://services.example.com -> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\services
```

Is this setup possible?  What do I need to do in IIS to get this configuration to work?  If a 30X HTTP response code is returned by the solution, that can't break any existing clients (probably .NET clients using a Web Service reference).

Comment: Don't be too harsh on the "old hotness" :) One "complexity" you'll likely hit, if you're saying "virtual application directory", will be configuration inheritance...

Comment: ASMX works inside applications that include MVC. Though I [don't recommend you use ASMX](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) anymore. Instead, you should upgrade your application to .NET 4.5 and use ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: @mason I know.  That can't be done because it would break existing clients who are none too enthusiastic about having to re-write their interfaces.